# Angularjs $http.post, passing array to PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using a service to update a DB table.

```
myApp.factory('createGal', function ($http, $q)
{
    return {
        createGal: function ()
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var newGalleryArray = {};

            newGalleryArray.galleryName = 'New Image Gallery';
            newGalleryArray.client      = 245;

            $http.post('/beta/images/create', {newGalleryArray: newGalleryArray}).success(function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

**PHP**

```
public function create()
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

The array is returning empty. Am i passing the array incorrectly?

**Chrome Dev**
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What's the console say about the request?

Comment: successful, request. Returns the DB action, just the array not being sent over in POST

Comment: Interesting... what is your PHP sending back?

Comment: Right now I am just trying to get PHP to print $_POST. It's returning Array ()....

Comment: How about `$_POST['newGalleryArray']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used PHP, but doesn't `$_POST` just contain request paramaters? `$http.post` sends data through a JSON payload, not request parameters. So, you'll need to use something like [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: DOH!! Just had to add $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Comment: If you have jQuery on the side send your post data through $.params and add Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to the request header. This way you can just use the $_POST global.